# Can one retrieve virtual terminal transactions with PayPal REST API?

Tags: rest, paypal

I have built a tool that uses REST API to pull all payments and create various reports.  However, I do not see any of the transactions completed via the Virtual Terminal.

The person that used the virtual terminal printed out the approved page, so I know that transactions were done on the 2015-11-19 yet these don't show up in my query results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think those will come back in the REST API, no.  You can use the Classic API to get them, though.  Specifically, [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=transactionsearch) would return the list of transactions, and then you can use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=gettransactiondetails) to pull more details for any given transaction.

If you're working with PHP you can use this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to make those calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: If this turns out to be true, I will drive down to PayPal and slap as many of their developers as possible.

Comment: It would be quicker to just use the Classic API and move forward with your life.  ;)